# Is it illegal to drive with a dirty car in Belarus?

Tags: traffic, driving

I just saw on Fifth Gear (a UK TV car show) that it was illegal to drive a dirty car in Belarus. A Google search revealed many other people believe this to be true.

Can anyone confirm it is true and explain why?

Comment: [Driving in Belarus](http://www.belarus.by/en/travel/driving) doesn't say anything about that, although as you say it's commonly repeated around the internet.

Comment: Sounds like a great question for [Skeptics.SE] :-)

Comment: according to [The Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/travelnews/9954389/Beware-unusual-driving-laws-in-Europe.html) it's really illegal, but I still can't find official source.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is true, but in a very unspectacular way.

[The official traffic laws state](http://pdd.by/pdd/en/10/):

> 10. The driver is prohibited to:
>
> ...
>
> 10.3 participate in road traffic on a vehicle covered with dirt (laminations), limiting the driver's field of vision and also making indiscernible the information on the registration plate at a distance of 40 meters and less

So - yes, you can be fined ([up to 300,000 Belarus Rubles](http://pdd.by/pdd/resp/), that is, up to about [30$](http://byr.fxexchangerate.com/usd/300000-currency-rates.html)) for having a dirty vehicle - but only if you can't see the road or the police can't see your licence plate. This is legislation the kinds of which have been seen in many a country.

Comment: thanks. I would have thought that was the case in all countries.

Comment: Unless I'm much mistaken, at the very least, the "making indiscernible the information on the registration plate" isn't Belarus invention. Same rules apply in USA and probably everywhere else

Comment: I used to work in a place where the vast majority of winter speeding violations caught by a speeding camera outside the workplace were useless, as license plates were covered in snow.

Comment: @gerrit - here's evidence for USA: [one](http://www.legalmatch.com/law-library/article/license-plate-laws.html), [two](http://www.stjamessheriff.com/PressRoom/PressRoomDisplay.asp?p1=1220&p2=Y)

Comment: @DVK I did not mean to challenge your claim.  I'm pretty sure that the same rules apply in Sweden but it appears Swedish road police have other priorities during a snowstorm than to enforce this rule (yes, some people are speeding in snowstorms)